# Check which PKs in List of PKs is present within SQFLITE database

Tags: flutter, dart

For a list of PKs of length k:

listPK = [1,2,3...k]

I'm currently running a for loop, and querying the database *k* times to check whether the item is present within the database or not.

```
List<bool> isPresent(List listPK)async{
  final db = await database;
  List<bool> output = List.filled(listPK.length, false)
  for (var i = 0; i<listPk.length; i++){
    List<Map> result = await db.query('elements', where: "id = ?", whereArgs: listPk[i]);
    if (result[0] != null) {output[i] = true}
  }
}
```

Was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this. I only want to know if the id is present within the database or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `WHERE ... IN` to check against all the IDs in one call.

```dart
String listQuery = listPK.join(', '); // "1, 2, 3, ..., k"
String query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id IN ($listQuery);`;
List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery(query);
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to query the database once and get all the id's in the 'elements' table. Once you have all the id's in the 'elements' table you can iterate through and find which id's are present and which are not.

Comment: The only way this would be more efficient is if the database is small and `k` is huge.